# In equation involving absolute value one solution might get rejected, why is that?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

For example the equation $|2x-1|+3=4x$,

We can get two equations out of that, $2x-1=4x-3$ and $2x-1=-(4x-3)$. Solve the first one we get $x=1$ and for the second one $x=2/3$. But when you substitute 2/3 into the original equation, you get 10/3=8/3, which is clearly wrong. My answer sheet says the answer is rejected, but if we follow all steps correctly and get to a solution, how can it still be wrong? It's like solving $5=3+x$ and x somehow doesn't equal to two.

Comment: Because 4x-3<0 when x=⅔.

Comment: You are thinking too procedurally, and are not considering the actual definition of the absolute value.  *Why* are you able to write the two equations $2x-1=4x-3$ and $2x-1 = -(4x-3)$?  Are there any conditions on either of those equations?

Comment: The answer is simple: you are not following "the" steps correctly, id est, the method that you are using does not guarantee that at each passage the solution set is unchanged. There are definitely ways to compute while preserving the solution set at each passage, bt they involve you tansforming equations into disjunctions of systems of inequations. From what I can see on the internet, it would seem like this is not a fashionable thing to teach in school anymore. Too bad for those people.

Answer (score 2):

Because:
$$|2x-1|+3=4x \implies 2x-1=4x-3 \lor 2x-1=-(4x-3)$$
and the converse is false.

Which means that any solution of LHS is also solution of RHS, but the converse is not necessary true. This is why if you perform a non-reversible derivation, you need to check the solutions in the original equation.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value of a number cannot be negative.

Observe that $2x - 1 \geq 0 \implies x \geq \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Hence, $|2x - 1| = 2x - 1$ if $x \geq 1/2$.  On the other hand, if $x < 1/2$, then $2x - 1 < 0$, so $|2x - 1| = -(2x - 1) = -2x + 1 > 0$.  Therefore, we obtain the piecewise definition

$$
|2x - 1| = \begin{cases}
           2x - 1 & \text{if $x \geq \dfrac{1}{2}$}\\[2 mm]
           -2x + 1 & \text{if $x < \dfrac{1}{2}$}
           \end{cases}
$$

Thus, we must consider cases, depending on whether $x \geq 1/2$.

**Case 1:** If $x \geq 1/2$,
\begin{align*}
|2x - 1| + 3 & = 4x\\
|2x - 1| & = 4x - 3\\
2x - 1 & = 4x - 3\\
2 & = 2x\\
1 & = x
\end{align*}
Since $1 \geq 1/2$, $x = 1$ is a solution, as you can verify by direct substitution.

**Case 2:** If $x < 1/2$,
\begin{align*}
|2x - 1| + 3 & = 4x\\
|2x - 1| & = 4x - 3\\
-2x + 1 & = 4x - 3\\
4 & = 6x\\
\frac{2}{3} & = x
\end{align*}
However, $2/3 \geq 1/2$, so it is not satisfy the restriction that $x < 1/2$.  Therefore, $x = 2/3$ is not a valid solution, as you can verify by direct substitution.